# Camunda returns error HTCL-02007 when calling API on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, api, camunda, camunda-modeler

I followed this tutorial [Web service call](https://medium.com/@stephenrussett/handling-government-business-processes-across-administrative-divisions-digitalstate-406f86d4fd56), and it works just fine.
Then I tried to call a simple local API, built in .net 6

```
https://localhost:7169/WeatherForecast/GetStatus
```

which returns

```
{
  "weather": "Good"
}
```

but when I try to start the process in Camunda task list, I always get error

```
The process could not be started. :
HTCL-02007 Unable to execute HTTP request
```

I tried to add cors to my API project, but in vain.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just try without SSL port like below

```
http://localhost:7169/WeatherForecast/GetStatus
```

I think there is an issue with local `IIS SSL` certificate.

Answer (score 0):

its possible that next Camunda node has wrong config .
for example according to image if you have unsuteble config in Point B, Camunda will lose the Url for CompleteA!

[image]